# why is AbstractOwnableSynchronizer exclusiveOwnerThread accessed through a final accessor?

Tags: java

here is the source code from JDK11:

```
package java.util.concurrent.locks;
public abstract class AbstractOwnableSynchronizer implements java.io.Serializable {
    private transient Thread exclusiveOwnerThread;
    protected final void setExclusiveOwnerThread(Thread thread) {
        exclusiveOwnerThread = thread;
    }
    protected final Thread getExclusiveOwnerThread() {
        return exclusiveOwnerThread;
    }
}
```

what's the point of using an accessor instead of using the field directly? since the accessor methods are final, why just not declare: `protected transient Thread exclusiveOwnerThread;` and remove the accessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of possible reasons:

- Future proofing.  If they want to put some logic into the getter and setter in the future, this allows them to do it.
- Possible backwards compatibility<sup>1</sup>.  Maybe the getter and setter >did< have some logic in the past.
- Changing the class *now* (as you suggest) would potentially break compatibility for customer code.

I expect that code author (Doug Lea) chose to use a getter and setter here because he thought it was the right way to do it.  In general, the stronger the abstraction boundaries are, the less problems you will get with unwanted coupling.

---

It is highly unlikely that there are any real disadvantages in using a getter / setter here.  For example, calls to the getter and setter code are likely to be inlined by the JIT compiler.

---

<sup>1 - Not in this case.  The class was introduced in Java 6 and has not been changed since then.</sup>

Comment: Another possible reason is so you can write method references for it.

Comment: That is true.  But that wasn't an issue back in Java 6 when this API was created.